# Managing Google Appengine App on Grandfathered Account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a grandfathered Google Apps for Work account since I had my appengine app running since before they started the whole Apps for Work thing and don't have to pay anything.

I haven't touched the actual app since long before the Apps for Work thing came around, and though I got the emails about it and opened the console once or twice, I haven't opened the app engine console forever.

I also have a google cloud platform account that I use for the VMs(not GAE).

The problem came when I went to actually update my app. I found that while the app is most definitely still running and accessible, and while my Apps for Work console still lists it, when I try to manage it, it redirects me to my cloud platform account, which has no GAE apps. I haven't even touched GAE on my cloud platform account, and there were no apps listed, just the docs.

So how do I access my app and edit it?